# How to clear the screen? (PYTHON)

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IduEi.png)I'm talking about the black thing on the right (sorry, I don't know the technical term for it) without actually restarting the thing. I want it to keep all the values and stuff, just clear the screen. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with screen? The console?

Comment: Try `print("\n"*32)`

Comment: "On the right"? My shell, the Windows command prompt, is just one big black rectangle. If your thing is divided in half or something, you'll need to be more specific about what kind of environment you're working in.

Comment: Provide a screenshot

Comment: If it is an ANSI terminal, you can use `print('\x1b[2J')`

Comment: Press "clear" button (not kidding)

Comment: Please provide more information about your system (i.e., OS, Python environment, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> cls
>   The 'cls' or clear screen function clears the screen in the interpreter while preserving the session.